# python function not returning expected string

Tags: python

I have a program that scans input text looking for a command. A command is in caps and surrounded by <>  symbols.

Part of this program includes a function which scans ahead for the next command

```
def nextCommand(command):
    lar = command.find("<LAR>")
    #...etc (stripped out variable defs used in statements below)
    if lar != -1 and lar > sma or lar > med or lar > bar or lar > fba or lar > fee or lar > lef or lar > rig or lar > cen or lar > end:
        print "nextCommand - lar:" + str(lar)
        return str("<LAR>")
    if sma != -1 and sma > lar or sma > med or sma > bar or sma > fba or sma > fee or sma > lef or sma > rig or sma > cen or sma > end:
        print "nextCommandsma:" + str(sma)
        return str("<SMA>")
        #stripped out more checks
    else:
        return str("")
```

This gets called in the main program

```
    print_text = ""
            if str(nextCommand(input_string)) != "":
                    next_command = str(nextCommand(input_string))
                    print "value recieved from nextCommand() is: " + str(nextCommand)
```

If I input 
    123 SMA 456 LAR 789
instead of seeing SM> I am seeing: (took out < symbols as s/o thinks its part of an attack)
"value recieved from nextCommand() is:

```
function nextCommand at <0xb74ce1ec>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Why `str("<SMA>")`? `"<SMA>"` is a string already.

Comment: It wasnt originally but was sniffing around wrong trees when trying to debug it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have actually printed the representation of the function. Observe:

```
nextCommand # This references the function
```

And:

```
nextCommand() # This calls the function
```

---

I think you meant to put `next_command` here instead of `nextCommand`

```
print "value recieved from nextCommand() is: " + str(nextCommand)
```

Should be:

```
print "value recieved from nextCommand() is: " + next_command
```